# extern template DLLs and programs (crypto++)

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I've been using Crypto++ with VS2005 and VS2010 for a while now. But recently I needed to use it with and application directly. The same code compiles fine when I'm compiling as a DLL and does not compile when compiling as an application.

This is the smallest sample that reproduces the error is this (based on `cryptopp561\algparam.h:301 CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate`

```
class Base 
{
protected:
    virtual void MoveInto(void *p) const = 0;
};

template<class T>
class Test: public Base
{
public:
    void MoveInto(void * buffer) const
    {
        Test<T> *x = new(buffer) Test<T>(*this);
    }
};

extern template class Test<bool>;
```

The compilation parameters are the same, only difference that I saw was the configuration type in the project ("Application (.exe)" generates the error and "Dynamic Library (.dll)" does not).

This is the compiler error:

```
main.h(15): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'buffer'
      main.h(14) : while compiling class template member function 'void Test<T>::MoveInto(void *) const'
      with
      [
          T=bool
      ]
      main.h(20) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Test<T>' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=bool
      ]
```

It seems to occur only when theres inheritance. Ommiting `: public Base` in the `class Test` declaration makes the error go away.

**EDIT:**
The problem was in a header included somewhere that defined a a debug version for `operator new` but didn't declared the placement new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you `#include <new>`, the header file that declares placement-new?

Comment: There was a header included somewhere that declared a debug version for new but did not declared the placement new version.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, extern templates are to tell the compiler to **not** instantiante at some point, so the second error does not make sense to me. Are you certain your compiler has support for extern templates? What if you do the opposite, explicit instantiation:

```
template class Test<bool>;
```

Comment: Removing the `extern` keyword has no effect at all. It seems to occur only when theres inheritance. Ommiting `: public Base` in the `class Test` declaration makes the error go away.

Comment: I tested the code in g++, it compiles without errors and does not seem invalid to me. Are you sure this is a really minimalistic example, or are there possibly bogus build settings? I'd recommend you check your example with another compiler, and then from the command line. Maybe this will put you into the right direction.

Comment: g++ really compiles it fine. I hope that there are bogus build settings so I would not need to hack inside Crypto++ library